# Image on click open a video that auto plays

Tags: javascript, html, video, modal-dialog, slider

I am creating a slider with images that when someone clicks one slide, opens a modal window with another slider with videos.

What I would like to achieve is: on click -> play the video. So if the third slide of the images is clicked, open and play the video automatically.

I think that the problem is here: `var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];` because this is affecting just the first slide.

Does anyone know how to apply that to all of the slides?

[Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hhLy4cng/13/)

Comment: What's the exact problem you are facing? You want to play video automatically on click?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do. If someone clicks the second slide, for example, auto play the second video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through you are code and found some minor bugs. I guess you forgot to add `vimeo library`. There were couple of changes which I did

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $(".center").slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerMode: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      lazy: true
    });

    $(".play").click(function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        var iframe = $('.active .vimeo-player')
        var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe)
        player.play()
      },700)
    })
  });
```

Currently it will play clicked vidoes, there are other edge cases also which you need to deal with like stopping the video on `escape key press` or on closing modal [updated fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hhLy4cng/51/). Mark this as accepted answer if it helps you.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! And do you know if there's a way to pause the video when the slides change? So if I am watching the first slide and I scroll to the second slide, pause the first slide.

Comment: $('#lightbox').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {var iframe = $('.active .vimeo-player')
        var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe)
        player.pause()
  })  // add this to your file. Carousel provide some callback methods which are called once a slide is changed.